# Android Emulator / Flutter sharp edges in the emulator

Tags: android, flutter, emulation

My emulator look like this.
The edges of the text and outline are sharp. I tested this on several different emulated devices. After compilation everything is ok and everything looks good.
What can I do to make the emulator smoother?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you more explain, where is problem?

Comment: See the text in the picture. It looks like the photo is in poor quality. And indeed this is what my emulator looks like. There are no slim edges and everything looks angular.

Comment: Did you try another emulator? With another resolution

Comment: Yes, i did. The same :(

Comment: Did you check app view on physical device?

Comment: Yeah, I checked. It's exactly the same.
Today I will check an older version of sdk.

Comment: Can you show your code? What do you create these fields?

Comment: I can, but this is not about code.
See the first screenshot. On the android bar. The 'Serial console enabled' lettering is pixelated.